# delayed load time for js file

Tags: javascript, html, css

so i made a script to change the css file linked depending on time of year. however the load time is too slow when changing page and refeshing, causing my page to load without css for a few seconds. Any thoughts on how to do this? i tried defer and async and changing the listed order of the linked files but it doesnt either, i have a feeling my js code is too slow and changing the href attribute may be an inefficient way for it to work. Any help would be most appreciated

aformentioned html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  
      <script type="module" src="localimports/scripts/script_for_site_themes.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="localimports/css/style.css">
    <script src="localimports/navbars/header.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
    <script src="localimports/navbars/footer.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
        <link id="sitebirthday" rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <link id="october" rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <link id="christmas" rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <link id="newyear" rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <link id="normal" rel="stylesheet" href="">


    
    

  </head>
  <body>
  

    <header-component>
    </header-component>
    <main>
```

below is the linked js file named script_for_site_themes.js that i call on to get my css file

```
 setInterval(function () {
        var date = new Date();
        var isodate = new Date().toISOString()

        if (date.getMonth()  === 11 && date.getDate()  === 12) {

                                    document.getElementById("sitebirthday").href="https://www.google.co.uk";



        }


        if (date.getDate()  === 9 ) {

                                    document.getElementById("october").href="https://www.google.co.uk";

        }

         if (date.getMonth()  === 11 ) {

                                    document.getElementById("christmas").href="https://www.google.co.uk";



        }


         if (date.getMonth()  === 0 ) {

                                    document.getElementById("newyear").href="https://www.google.co.uk";

        }
        
        
        
         else {

                                    document.getElementById("normal").href="../localimports/css/templateofcssthemes.css";

        }


        








    }, 1000)
```

```
</main>  <br>

<footer-component></footer-component>
```

Comment: Do you have to to load this css files separately with? you could put all the css you need in one file and use CSS selectors to target the stylings based on the time of the year.

Comment: If possible you'd want to get all this done on the server side of the site. Is there any backend involved in your situation?

Comment: If this must be done locally: `setInterval` will run repeatedly until the timer is cancelled. This should only be needed once per page load though, so `setTimeout` may be a better option. You could also simplify testing by declaring a named function with an argument of either a date timestamp or the current month, so you can make sure it's applying the different themes properly. Finally, set a default style to show while the special sheet is loaded to prevent showing unstyled content.

Answer (score 2):

You could pull all the css you need in one file and use css selectors to target the stylings based on the time of the year. you could do something like this

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Simple HTML Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <main id="theme" class="">
    This is the main content of the page. You can add paragraphs, headings, images, and other elements here.
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
 .october {
      color: red;
    }
    
    .christmas {
      color: blue;
    }
    
    .newyear {
      color: green;
    }
    
    .normal {
      color: yellow;
    }
```

**JS**

```
const monthNames = ["january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june",
  "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december"
];

function setThemeClass() {
  const today = new Date();
  const currentMonth = monthNames[today.getMonth()]; // Get current month

  const mainElement = document.getElementById("theme");
  let themeClass = "normal"; // Default class

  switch (currentMonth) {
    case "october":
      themeClass = "october";
      break;
    case "december":
      themeClass = "christmas";
      break;
    case "january":
      themeClass = "newyear";
      break;
  }

  mainElement.classList.add(themeClass); // Add the class to the main tag
}

window.onload = setThemeClass;
```

Comment: heyyy, sorry for the late reply, whilst this works, how would i add a specific date like lets say the 14th of june? sorry , im very bad when it comes to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `window.onload` solution. This fires when all the content has fully loaded (stylesheets, images, etc)

```
window.onload = function() {
  // Your JS code
  console.log("Page Loaded!");
};
```

Comment: thanks but its still to slow, way faster, but not fast enough